# how to exit the while loop - when counterPosition >=100 start a new game

Tags: python

write code to simulate the game for one player and calculate the number of dice throws required to finish a game. The user should be allowed to specify the number of games simulated and the code should calculate the average number of dice throws per game.

```
import random

def diceRoll():
    return random.randint (1,6)

userInput = int(input("How many games would you like to play snakes and ladders?"))

totalDiceRolls = 0

for i in range(userInput):

counterPosition = 0

while (counterPosition < 100):
    totalDiceRolls += 1
    currentDiceRoll = diceRoll()
    counterPosition += currentDiceRoll

    if counterPosition == 1:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 37
    if counterPosition == 4:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 10
    if counterPosition == 9:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 22
    if counterPosition == 21:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 21
    if counterPosition == 28:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 56
    if counterPosition == 51:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 16
    if counterPosition == 72:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 19
    if counterPosition == 80:
        counterPosition = counterPosition + 19
    if counterPosition == 17:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 10
    if counterPosition == 54:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 20
    if counterPosition == 63:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 4
    if counterPosition == 64:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 4
    if counterPosition == 87:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 51
    if counterPosition == 92:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 19
    if counterPosition == 95:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 20
    if counterPosition == 98:
        counterPosition = counterPosition - 19
    if counterPosition >= 100:


avgRolls = totalDiceRolls / userInput
print("The average number of rolls per game is", avgRolls)
```

Comment: Was this exact question not just asked about half an hour ago or so...?

Comment: yeah lol still cant figure it out

Comment: Well, playGame doesn't return anything, so adding its result to a number makes little sense.

Comment: where is the duplicate

Comment: how do I fix it then?

Comment: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback). There are other usefull information, ie. which line make problem. Now you show only last part of error message.

Comment: I run this code and get different error - `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'` - you show different code than you run. You can't get your error with this code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ben/Desktop/snakes and ladders version 3.py", line 17, in <module>
    totalDiceRolls += playGame()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: always put IN QUESTION.

Comment: changed the name of the question to the error message now

Comment: use code from previous question. You changed everything and now `playGame()` doesn't do what it should do. Or remove `totalDiceRolls += playGame()` and put there `currentDiceRoll = 0`.

Comment: omg thank you so much now how do i exit the whil loop

Answer (score 0):

You changed everything in code from previous question/answer and now it doesn't work.

You had `playGame():` with `while` loop inside but you moved `while` outside , but you didn't move rest of elements.

Previously `playGame():` returned number of dice rolls and you could add it to `totalDiceRolls`

```
totalDiceRolls += playGame()
```

but now `playGame()` returns `None` and you get error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Working code - without `playGame()`

```
import random

def diceRoll():
    return random.randint (1,6)

userInput = int(input("How many games would you like to play snakes and ladders?"))

totalDiceRolls = 0

for i in range(userInput):

    counterPosition = 0 #setting counterposition and diceroll to 0

    while (counterPosition < 100):
        totalDiceRolls += 1
        currentDiceRoll = diceRoll()
        print("The currentDiceroll is", currentDiceRoll)

        counterPosition += currentDiceRoll

        if counterPosition == 1: #all the if statements show what happens if the one player lands on a snake or a ladder
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 37
        if counterPosition == 4:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 10
        if counterPosition == 9:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 22
        if counterPosition == 21:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 21
        if counterPosition == 28:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 56
        if counterPosition == 51:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 16
        if counterPosition == 72:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 19
        if counterPosition == 80:
            counterPosition = counterPosition + 19
        if counterPosition == 17:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 10
        if counterPosition == 54:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 20
        if counterPosition == 63:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 4
        if counterPosition == 64:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 4
        if counterPosition == 87:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 51
        if counterPosition == 92:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 19
        if counterPosition == 95:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 20
        if counterPosition == 98:
            counterPosition = counterPosition - 19
        if counterPosition >= 100:
            print ("Congratulations end of game")

avgRolls = totalDiceRolls / userInput
print("The average number of rolls per game is", avgRolls)
```